# How to add pagination based on amount of data

Tags: codeigniter, pagination, codeigniter-3

I have had 2 different display from a website that is shaped like a tab menu. For the first tab menu, data displayed does not require pagination, however for the second tab menu, data displayed requires pagination because the amount of data a lot.

How to display both of the data if the first tab menu did not need the presence of pagination and the second tab menu need pagination ??
Give me any suggestions step to resolve this.....

Comment: Go from basics. Find some topics here or tutorials on the web about pagination. Even CI userguide pagination page should be sufficient. First make easier one. Also, without code of what have you done so far and determining point where you stuck, noone can help.

Comment: Codeigniter have a good documentation on pagination. Here is the [link](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/pagination.html) . It may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Either build pagination the normal way (with page refreshes, see the links in the comments to your question) and save a parameter to know that you're busy in the 2nd tab, or use ajax to load the paginated data in the 2nd tab. This requires you to build an api like functionality to obtain this paginated data as json and build the page with javascript. From the api you would call a method on your model that uses LIMIT and OFFSET to get the right data section.